# Find all my questions answered by a particular helper

Tags: discussion, search

I want to check all my questions answered by one person.

Is it possible to handle such a task?

Comment: It is probably possible, but why do you need that?

Comment: I intend to find a great answer @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854469

Comment: Sometimes, a simple network-wide fulltext search at https://stackexchange.com suffices.

Comment: You can use [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368237/4284627).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a good UI built into the sites for this, but you can do it with a SEDE query. I wrote one for you:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854477/find-all-of-your-questions-answered-by-a-particular-user?YourUserID=3771&HelperUserID=5745

SEDE is a publicly available/queryable copy of the database that backs the SE sites. The only downside is that it's not updated in real time, so you may miss out on recent activity ([up to a week old](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq)) depending on when you hit it.

Answer (score 2):

You could look on that user's profle page by clicking their name, then answers, newest, and look for your questions in the list.

[image: Newest Answers example]
It's not quite what you asked for, but it's probably the closest the average user would get within the current UI.

Maybe there could be room for a "related to me" option here....